# ¿se puede hacer una relación sobre otra relacion?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Estoy modificando una base de datos relacional y en el modelo E/R, me encuentro con que tengo la tabla usuarios contratan(relacion) bonos.

Pero aquí viene el problema, necesito ir sabiendo que bono contrata cada usuario y a un bono se le aplica una actuación (Es decir a un contrato) aquí es donde tengo mi problema.

podría sacar una relación de contratan a actuación¿?? la tabla bonos solo se usa para almacenar los tipos de bonos.

la relación entre usuarios y bonos es de M:N pero si un usuario contrata un nuevo bono, tengo que saber que bono tenía anteriormente, que bono quiere ahora, el tiempo restante del bono anterior y las actuaciones sobre ese bono anterior... Pero si es usuario contrata un nuevo bono, se actualiza el tiempoRestante se suma con el tiempo que tuviera y se actualiza el tipo de bono que tuviera por el que quiere ahora, sea el mismo o no

Había pensado en añadir a la relación contratan, ya que ahí sale una nueva tabla, los atributos usuario, fechaContratoPrimerBono, el bono,TiempoRestante, si está activo, si solicita uno nuevo, pues cual, el tiempo que solicita para actualizar al bono anterior y como debo saber el bono anterior, otra columna bonoAnterior y fechaBonoAnterior. Todo esto iría en la relación contratan (Es lo que había pensado)

Ahora se relacionaría a través de aplica con actuacion (a un contrato se le aplica una actuación) y estaría relacionada con una cardinalidad 1:N y en actuación registrar el código de contrato

**No estoy pidiendo que me lo resolváis, es solo saber como podría hacerlo mejor, porque necesito generar un histórico**

Gracias por la ayuda y oajalá se entienda.

Un saludo

Comment: No se si entendi bien, lo voy a explicar a mi manera, necesitas obtener 3 datos diferentes, el usuario, la contratacion y el historial de que cual bono tiene cada uno cierto? podrias dividir eso en 3 tablas, el usuario, los tipos de bono que existen y el historial de cada uno

Comment: @ernestojimenez gracias por tu respuesta eso es lo que inicialmente tenia en la base de datos. Pero por ejemplo, para posteriormente hacer una consulta a la base de datos, donde iría mostrando la fecha de contratación de cada bono, luego las actuaciones van aplicadas a un bono... pues de alguna manera tengo que hacer una relación ahí.... No se como plantearlo

Comment: a ver has esto, puedes relacionar: id del usuario, el id del bono en el historial, luego ingresa el id del usuario, el id del bono, y la fecha en la que lo solicito, cuando realices la consulta te saldran todas las solicitudes que el usuario halla hecho y su fecha, si lo ordenas deberia salirte el primero como el actual

Comment: @ernestojimenez gracias de nuevo por tu respuesta. Si definitivamente voy a arreglar la tabla historial y lo voy a hacer así. Pero si hago una relación entre bonos e historial, saldría una relación M:N y ahí voy almacenando lo que me has dicho, y si también añado los campos de tiempoRestante, etc etc... desde esa misma tabla podría aplicar una actuación¿?? para que quede reflejada también esa info

Comment: o puedes dividrlo en 4 tablas, usuarios, lista de bonos, bono actual y su historial donde en el historial registraras todos los datos que necesites y en el bono actual solo ingresaras las actualizaciones que se soliciten

Comment: Osea es algo asi? Si el usuario tiene un bono activo y dura hasta cierta fecha pero quiere cambiarse de bono y pide la actualizacion, entonces hace la solicitud y dice: te quedan X dias para vencer este bono y cambiar al nuevo? o algo asi ?

Comment: @ernestojimenez si y no. El usuario tiene un bono... con x minutos, se le generan unas actuaciones sobre una asistencia que ha solicitado, pero esas actuaciones pienso, que deberían de ir relacionadas con el bono que tenga para restarle minutos. Si el user, quiere otro bono, se le debe de sumar los min que tenga + los del nuevo y actualizar el tipo de bono que tiene. El problema está en esa actualización, porque debo saber que bonos va teniendo y las actuaciones a que bono se están aplicando

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116654/discussion-between-ernesto-jimenez-and-scorpions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se ha resuelto, como el usuario @ernestojimenez me recomendó. Un par de tablas más, una de historial y otra de contrato. También añadir en la tabla usuarios las columnas de codigo de contrato y código de bono.

Ha sido una buena solución, fácil de implementar tanto en e modelo como en código.

Gracias